# Tunnelblick VPN is blocking internet even when not using it

Tags: macos, vpn, internet

I installed a custom tunnelblick to access my University VPN.
Now I can't access internet (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG), even if the VPN (or tunnelblick itself) is off.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you know the issue is caused by the VPN? Does the internet work if you completely remove all traces of the VPN?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to remove it. I could uninstall tunnelblick but I'm afraid it could leave OpenVPN stuff in the system. I want to be sure of the correct way to act before doing it

Comment: Are you on macOS or iOS? Please add either the [macos] or [ios] tag to your question.